# How to add show/hide password image in a Xamarin.Forms Editor for ios project. (scrolling and UI placement issues)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitextview

I am trying to place a button to implement show/hide password in a custom `UITextView` in **Xamarin.iOS** (Editor in **Xamarin.Forms**). However I am facing two (2) issues with the UI design.

I have used this code used for the show/hide password button setup, and it works perfectly:

```
UITextView vUpdatedEntry = (UITextView)Control;
var buttonRect = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom);
buttonRect.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("show_black_24"), UIControlState.Normal);
buttonRect.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e1) => {
    if (vUpdatedEntry.SecureTextEntry)
    {
        vUpdatedEntry.SecureTextEntry = false;
        buttonRect.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("hide_black_24"), UIControlState.Normal);
    }
    else
    {
        vUpdatedEntry.SecureTextEntry = true;
        buttonRect.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("show_black_24"), UIControlState.Normal);
    }
};
```

**Issue 1**. I am unable to prevent the button from scrolling away when the `UITextView` scrolls. Whenever scrolling occurs, this happens:

[image: Scrolling-issue]

Basically the button scrolls along with the text which is not ideal. Any ideas on how to fix this would be much appreciated.

**Issue 2**. I am trying to get the button which allows the user to select whether they want the password to be visible or not to be on the **right** side of the `UITextView`. I have used the code below to do this.

```
buttonRect.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(10.0f, 0.0f, 15.0f, 15.0f);
buttonRect.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;
buttonRect.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;

UIView paddingViewRight = new UIView(new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f, 18.0f));
paddingViewRight.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Purple;
paddingViewRight.AddSubview(buttonRect);

buttonRect.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
buttonRect.CenterYAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(paddingViewRight.CenterYAnchor).Active = true;

vUpdatedEntry.TextContainerInset = new UIEdgeInsets(8.0f, 0.0f, 8.0f, paddingViewRight.Frame.Width+5.0f);
vUpdatedEntry.AddSubview(paddingViewRight);

paddingViewRight.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
paddingViewRight.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(vUpdatedEntry.LayoutMarginsGuide.TrailingAnchor, 9.0f).Active = true;
paddingViewRight.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(vUpdatedEntry.HeightAnchor).Active = true;
paddingViewRight.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(buttonRect.WidthAnchor,1.0f, 0.0f).Active = true;

Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 4;
Control.Layer.BorderColor = new CoreGraphics.CGColor(255, 255, 255);
Control.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
vUpdatedEntry.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Left;
```

and it gives me this:

[image: My solution]

This is my desired **visual** outcome, as it looks like the image below when the background colors are removed:

[image: My solution-2]

However, this solution feels rather *hacky* with lots of constants used in places where I would expect that using an `AutoLayout` anchor property should have worked. I tried using the `TrailingAnchor` property with `ConstraintEqualTo` to achieve this (***this*** being stickiness to the right side of `UITextView`), but it kept sticking to the left-side instead. A cleaner approach to achieving this would be much appreciated

Comment: To the issue 1, I would recommend you to not give a frame to buttonRect, instead use autolayout to layout the buttonRect. To the issue 2, I would use the same approach as yours to achieve it.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Hello, thanks for your input to this. You didn't necessarily give me the answer but you did get me thinking in the right direction, and I was able to solve **Issue 1** using `paddingViewRight.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(vUpdatedEntry.LayoutMarginsGuide.BottomAnchor, 6.0f)`.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I was also hoping you could explain why I have to use `.LayoutMarginsGuide` when using constraints with the `Anchors`. I am able to make the left edge of `paddingViewRight` stick to the left edge of `vUpdatedEntry` using `paddingViewRight.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(vUpdatedEntry.LeadingAnchor)`. However this does not work when try to do same with the `TrailingAnchor`. I have to use `.LayoutMarginsGuide`, with a constant as the second argument it order to get my desired result, and I was hoping you could explain why this is so or suggest some resources that explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Inspiration, from @JackHua-MSFT (the poster of comment on the question) I was able to figure out how to fix **Issue 1** which was the more pressing issue in the question, My code below:.

```
buttonRect.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;

UIView paddingViewRight = new UIView(new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f, 18.0f));
paddingViewRight.AddSubview(buttonRect);

buttonRect.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
buttonRect.CenterYAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(paddingViewRight.CenterYAnchor).Active = true;

vUpdatedEntry.AddSubview(paddingViewRight);

paddingViewRight.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
paddingViewRight.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(vUpdatedEntry.LayoutMarginsGuide.TrailingAnchor, 8.0f).Active = true;
paddingViewRight.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(vUpdatedEntry.HeightAnchor).Active = true;
paddingViewRight.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(vUpdatedEntry.LayoutMarginsGuide.BottomAnchor).Active = true;
paddingViewRight.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(vUpdatedEntry.LayoutMarginsGuide.TopAnchor, -8.0f).Active = true;
paddingViewRight.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(buttonRect.WidthAnchor, 1.0f, 3.0f).Active = true;
vUpdatedEntry.TextContainerInset = new UIEdgeInsets(8.0f, 0.0f, 8.0f, paddingViewRight.Frame.Width + 5.0f);

Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 4;
Control.Layer.BorderColor = new CoreGraphics.CGColor(255, 255, 255);
Control.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
vUpdatedEntry.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Left;
```

However any suggestions for a cleaner solution **(specifically one where I don't need to use constant float values with the LayoutMarginsGuide)** would be appreciated. Also an explanation on the difference between using `.TopAnchor` and `.BottomAnchor` (which I tried using but didn't work) vs `.LayoutMargins.TopAnchor` and `.LayoutMargins.BottomAnchor` would be appreciated. :)

Comment: If I understand right, set equal TopAnchor ,BottomAnchor  has the same result of setting equal height.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT That is what I would expect, but removing the Height Anchor  constraint causes excess space between `paddingViewRight` and the bottom of the `UITextView`